# How I do event with DropDownList read SQL rows and pass values on textbox?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

When I select a value in a DropDownList of DevExpress, how I could pass datatables or rows (SQL) in a textbox?.

More Specific:

When I click 1 value on DropDownList (DevExpress control) [for example "Countries"], I choose "USA", in other control (Textbox in this case) this appear automatically the text value "Washington DC" (read it from the same SQL datatable)

Is in Visual Studio 2013 ASPX .NET VB (Winforms)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program the click event of dropdownlist and used the value your chose like query parameter.

```
Try
    Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\My Documents\Bd1.mdb")

        'Create a comand
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()

        'Indicates the query you will execute
        cmd.CommandText = _
            "SELECT SUM(name field) AS Suma FROM NameTable"

        'Open the connection
        cnn.Open()

        'Execute the query
        Dim suma As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        ' Show the formatted result in control TextBox
        TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", suma)

    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

End Try
```